# how to find element.style {

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea how to find the source of this element style codes. Such as at the right part of the Chrome Element Inspector Tool it shows this CSS code:

[image]

ineed to delete for fix the problem

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That style is the style set directly on the element, in the `style="width:0px"` attribute.

It could either be written like that in the source HTML, or potentially set on the element via JavaScript.

Comment: how to resolve please im new

Comment: What are you trying to resolve? Are you trying to remove it?

Comment: yes ineed to delete

Comment: Do you have access to the original source for those elements? Include it in the question if you do please.

Comment: yes ihave all Access for original  elements

Comment: it's possible send you file source